# Low WLAN throughput despite claimed fast connection

Tags: wifi

I have so following setup and suffering from low throughput and high latency and I have no clue why thats the case:

Server (192.168.2.2) <--> AP (192.168.2.1) <--> Laptop (192.168.2.12)
The server is running debian.
Here the data form laptop:

```
iwconfig 
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"abc"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 44:44:67:E3:C9:25   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:48   Missed beacon:0
```

Here some data from the server
    iwconfig 
    lo        no wireless extensions.

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

sit0      no wireless extensions.

ip6tnl0   no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"abc"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 44:44:67:E3:C9:25   
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=84/100  Signal level=46/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

tun0      no wireless extensions.
```

I was measuring the connection speed using iperf, here is the data from the server:

```
iperf -s -p 80
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 80
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------                            
[  4] local 192.168.2.2 port 80 connected with 192.168.2.12 port 55385                  
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth                                             
[  4]  0.0-12.5 sec   384 KBytes   252 Kbits/sec
```

Also the ping is quite high, normally between 100-200 msec.

Not sure if its helpful, but here the iptables rules from the server:

```
iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

----------------------EDIT---------------

Now I connected the laptop via cable (eth0, ip: 192.168.2.13) to the AP and tried the same, here the results:

```
ping 192.168.2.2
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.19 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=105 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=62.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=84.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=110 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=2.42 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=72.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=95.0 ms

iperf -c 192.168.2.2 -p 80
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.2, TCP port 80
TCP window size: 22.9 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.2.13 port 51441 connected with 192.168.2.2 port 80
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.1 sec  6.12 MBytes  5.07 Mbits/sec
```

What could cause this slow down?

Comment: Other wireless networks at the area. Have you tried changing channels?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, yes, there are roughly 7 other networks. But none of those I can choose from (1-13) performs significantly better. Btw. should this kind of interference be considered in the data rate provided by iwconfig?